# How can I get date like(07.11.2021 ) from date name like (Monday,Tuesday...)

Tags: python, django

I' developing a django project and in my template user can select a day.As shown as bottom picture.
[image]

And after day select post request is working.And in my views.py I can get the day name.Like(Monday,Tuesday,...). Using this knowledge, I want to get a date this week. For example, the coming value of request is Wednesday, and I want to get what date is Wednesday this week like (03.11.2021)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I couldn't actually transfer what I thought to the code

Comment: Is the day name just a string? Does it have to be in the future? If today is `Wednesday`, and the user selects `Tuesday`, should it give next week Tuesday's date?

Comment: I think for that you have to post entire date. but hide the *date of the week ( 03.11.2021 )* field.

Comment: Fair enough, but I assume you have some code somewhere (which should fix if not all at least some of the loose ends you have in your question). Why not reporting it in the form of a [MWE](/help/mcve)? Also, even if you your attempt does not work it will help readers understand where you got stuck, otherwise everybody would be just doing guesswork. I'd also recommend going through [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: yes just string

Comment: @MuhammetAydoğan i have wrote an answer did you try it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a file called utils.py and import it inside your views.py and your can pass it string like 'Sunday' it will give the correct date and make sure the first later is capitalyze. before passing to the function.This is just an idea you can make it better ).

```
from datetime import date,timedelta
import calendar
def find_day(week_day):
    my_date = date.today()
    a = calendar.day_name[my_date.weekday()]  
    weekdays = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday']
    now = weekdays.index(a)
    later = weekdays.index(week_day)
    date = my_date - timedelta(days= now - later)
    return date
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues with the above code: (1) it depends on the actual date it is being run; (2) the name `date` is being rebound; (3) the name of the weekdays is defined both in `weekdays` and in `calendar.day_name` which means there are two sources for the same info; (4) the `if` is useless as both branches contain the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a certain data (e.g. today) and you want to know the date of another day of the week within the same week.

You could use `datetime` and `time`, to get the weekday as integer of today, compute the difference in days between the weekday you have and the one you target, and finally apply that difference to your original `datetime`.

The weekday is optionally converted to an integer using `strptime()` and trying all known weekday format strings. Do note that `tm_wday` as well as `weekday()` use the same convention for "Monday" -> 0 through "Sunday" -> 6, while `%w` and `%u` format codes use different conventions. It is crucial to compute the difference with integer weekdays obtained following the same convention. Hence, if `weekday` is given as an integer, the "Monday" -> 0 through "Sunday" -> 6 convention should be used.

```
import datetime
import time


def weekday_as_int(weekday):
    weekday = weekday.strip()
    result = None
    # %a -- Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name.
    # %A -- Weekday as locale’s full name.
    # %w -- Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday.
    # %u -- ISO 8601 weekday as a decimal number where 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday
    for fmt in ("%a", "%A", "%w", "%u"):
        try:
            result = time.strptime(weekday, fmt).tm_wday
        except ValueError:
            pass
        if result is not None:
            return result
    if not result:
        raise ValueError(f'Could not parse `{weekday}` as week day')


def get_date_for_weekday(curr_date, weekday):
    if not isinstance(weekday, int):
        weekday = weekday_as_int(weekday)
    curr_weekday = curr_date.weekday()
    delta = weekday - curr_weekday
    return curr_date + datetime.timedelta(days=delta)


# datetime.date(2021, 11, 5) is a Friday
get_date_for_weekday(datetime.date(2021, 11, 5), "Monday")
# datetime.date(2021, 11, 1)

get_date_for_weekday(datetime.date(2021, 11, 5), "Friday")
# datetime.date(2021, 11, 5)

get_date_for_weekday(datetime.date(2021, 11, 2), "wed")                                                                         
# datetime.date(2021, 11, 3)

get_date_for_weekday(datetime.date.today(), "mon")
# datetime.date(2021, 11, 1)  # <-- this output only this week
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will carefully examine.